# Can you edit the default Tampermonkey template?

Tags: tampermonkey

I know this sounds like a dumb question but I could not find an answer anywhere.
Is there a way to edit the default Tampermonkey template that comes up when you add a new script?

I use this a lot for my job and what I want to do is make the `@`s at the top to be the same each time I write a new script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the template on the settings page:

1. Click on the Tampermonkey icon (usually in the upper left).
2. Then click on *Dashboard*:
   [image: Open the dashboard]
3. Click on the *Settings* tab:
   [image: Settings tab]

   3.5 Be sure the *Config mode* setting is set to `Advanced`:
   [image: config mode]
4. Scroll down to the *Userscripts* section and edit the *New
   userscript template*.
5. Press the local <kbd>Save</kbd> button when done:
   [image: Save button]

---

A good, general purpose, base template is:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _YOUR_SCRIPT_NAME
// @include  http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==

GM_addStyle ( "                                 \
    #SAMPLE_ID {                                \
        margin:                 0;              \
        padding:                0;              \
    }                                           \
" );

waitForKeyElements ("ANY_VALID_JQUERY_SELECTOR", clickCategoryLink);

function clickCategoryLink (jNode) {
    var clickEvent  = document.createEvent ('MouseEvents');
    clickEvent.initEvent ('click', true, true);
    jNode[0].dispatchEvent (clickEvent);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Brock I see why I could not find it, I had the config mode set to novice which did not display the userscripts section on the settings page. I changed that to advanced and I was able to edit the template.